# Applescript JSON extraction

Tags: json, applescript

I have this JSON File and I need to extract data from it:

```
{
        "data1": "Hello",
        "data2":[
            {
                "value1": "1092",
                "value2": "1242",
                "value3": "4234",
            }
        ],
        "data3": "Bye"
}
```

I know how to get the value from `"data1"` and `"data3"` with this piece of code

```
set mJson to do shell script "curl -s 'https://apiURL...'"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {","}
set keyValueList to (every text item in mJson) as list
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""

set theKeyValuePair to item 3 of keyValueList
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {": "}
set theKeyValueBufferList to (every text item in theKeyValuePair) as list
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
set theValue to item 2 of theKeyValueBufferList
set value to do shell script "sed s/[^0-9.,]//g <<< " & theValue
return "$" & text 1 thru 7 of value
```

But how to get the value in `"data2"` > `"value1"` since it is in a "sub categorie" of the JSON file?

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing JSON with vanilla AppleScript is pretty annoying.

You can use a helper app like [JSON Helper](http://www.mousedown.net/mouseware/JSONHelper.html) or you can do it with the help from the Foundation framework

```
set json to "{\"data1\": \"Hello\",\"data2\":[{\"value1\": \"1092\",\"value2\": \"1242\",\"value3\": \"4234\",
}],\"data3\": \"Bye\"}"

set foundationString to current application's NSString's stringWithString:json
set jsonData to foundationString's dataUsingEncoding:(current application's NSUTF8StringEncoding)
set {dataDictionary, jsonError} to current application's NSJSONSerialization's JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 |error|:(reference)
if jsonError is missing value then
    set data1 to (dataDictionary's objectForKey:"data1") as text
    set data2 to (dataDictionary's objectForKey:"data2")'s objectAtIndex:0
    set value1 to (data2's objectForKey:"value1") as text
end if
```

Comment: JSON Helper really helped. Thanks vadian